# Powershell, Save web image using outvariable

Tags: image, powershell, file-io

I want to capture a web image into a variable for processing (see below).  I want to avoid saving it to a file, processing the file, then deleting the file.  I can save the web-request output directly to a file, as shown, but if I save the output to a variable then save the variable content to a file, I do not have the same result.

```
    # saving output to a file works
        $image='https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png'
        Invoke-WebRequest $image -outfile image1.png

    <# I want to skip creating a file, using it, then deleting it
    Save the image into a variable, convert to base64 to store in db, retrieve from db, convert back, save to a file
    #>
        Invoke-WebRequest $image -OutVariable imagevariable
        $imagevariable | out-file image2.png   # this is not a valid image

    # Convert to base64 (using PSCX add-on) to store string
        $toBase64=ConvertTo-Base64($imagevariable)

    # save to, retrieve from db
        #Invoke-Sqlcmd insert...
        #Invoke-Sqlcmd select...

    # Convert from base64 (using PSCX add-on)  & output to a file
        $fromBase64 | ConvertFrom-Base64 -OutputPath image3.png
```

For ease, I am going to use the [PSCX community extensions](https://pscx.codeplex.com/) for base64 conversion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are really close but the image bytes are in the returned object's `Content` property, try this:

```
$toBase64 = $imagevariable.Content | ConvertTo-Base64
```

Comment: KH, using your suggestion, I would expect this:
        Invoke-WebRequest $image -OutVariable imagevariable
        $imagevariable.content | out-file image2.png  to create a good png, but it does not.

Comment: That's because Out-File uses a default encoding of Unicode and is meant to output text not bytes.  Use this instead ` | Set-Content image2.png -Enc Byte`

Comment: '        Invoke-WebRequest $image -OutVariable imagevariable
        $imagevariable.content | set-content image2.png  -enc byte '      is the solution. Thank you Keith.  If you can take another moment, I would appreciate if you could annotate with a tech reference if you know one as I could not find something.

Comment: @Albert a tech reference on what specifically: Set-Content?

Comment: set-content gives the general overview. It doesn't reference `-encoding byte`, even [set-content for filesystem](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847827.aspx), which I just came across, didn't offer a suggestion toward your solution.